# Regular Expression to extract words across sentences

Tags: regex

My input is

```
The world is round. We meet everyone quite soon. It is a small world. Be happy.
```

I want sentences containing the words small and happy.
My regular expression is `[.]\\s*.*?small.*?happy.*?[.]`
The expected output is

```
It is a small world. Be happy.
```

but i get the output as

> . We meet everyone quite soon. It is a small world. Be happy.

Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below regex,

```
(?<=^|\. )[^.]*small.*?happy[^.]*\.
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qE6oS6/12)

Comment: Is the positive look-behind really necessary? I think `\b` will suffice.

Comment: it sets the matching marker at the start or just after to `\. ` where the next sentence usually begins. It's good if we provide a more appropriate regex.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a word boundary `\b` here.

```
\b[^.]*small.*?happy[^.]*\.
```

Or make your own boundary.

```
(?:^|\. )([^.]*small.*?happy[^.]*\.)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these regexes:

```
(?<!\.)[^.]*small[^.]*\.
(?<!\.)[^.]*happy[^.]*\.
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/gQ6fD4/1).

- `(?<!\.)` Asserts that we are not ahead of a single period, this allows matching after the whitespace between sentences.
- `[^.]*` Matches any character sequence that isn't a dot, thus effectively limiting between sentences.
- `happy` The character sequence **"happy"**.
- `[^.]*`
- `\.` Finishes the line with a period.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with following regex:

```
((?<=^|\. )[^.]*?(?:small|happy)[^.]*\.)
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/sY6nM3/1)

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [49-69] `It is a small world.`
MATCH 2
1.  [70-79] `Be happy.`
```